# The separator between keywords in PDF meta data

Tags: pdf, delimiter, keyword

I cannot find an "official" documentation on whether the keywords and keyword phrases in the meta data of a PDF file are to be separated by a comma or by a comma with space.

The following example demonstrates the difference:

- keyword,keyword phrase,another keyword phrase
- keyword, keyword phrase, another keyword phrase

Any high-quality references?

The online sources I found are of low quality.
E.g., an [Adobe press web page](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1998556&seqNum=7) says "keywords must be separated by commas or semicolons", but in the example we see a semicolon with a following space before the first keyword and a semicolon with a following space between each two neighbor keywords. We don't see keyword phrases in the example.

Answer (score 11):

The keywords metadata field is a single text field - not a list.  You can choose whatever is visually pleasing to you.  The search engine which operates on the keyword data may have other preferences, but I would imagine that either comma or semicolon would work with most modern search engines.

Reference: PDF 32000-1:2008 on page 550 at 1. [Adobe](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf); 2. [The Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20171201081318if_/http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

[ExifTool, for example](https://sourceforge.net/p/exiftool/code/ci/master/tree/lib/Image/ExifTool/PDF.pm#l1978) parses for comma separated values, but if it does not find a comma it will split on spaces:

```pl
# separate tokens in comma or whitespace delimited lists
my @values = ($val =~ /,/) ? split /,+\s*/, $val : split ' ', $val;
foreach $val (@values) {
    $et->FoundTag($tagInfo, $val);
}
```

Comment: For reference, Preview for Mac separates keywords on comma + space.

Comment: Would someone be so kind as to try the link associated with the words, "PDF 32000-1:2008 on page 550." I can find no document there anything like the one to which the author of this response alludes. For convenience, the link is http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf. I can't find any PDF there. Thanks!

Comment: @ClarPaul - yep.  Looks like they moved it.  I updated the link.

Comment: @Mitch, the link to PDF 32000-1:2008 went bad again. I found a new link to the original document at Adobe and an archived version associated with your last link correction. I submitted an edited version of your response that includes both links I found and excludes the dead one.

Comment: @ClarPaul, quite a fickle link. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

I dont have a "high-quality references" but, if i generated a pdf using latex i do it in the following way:
adding in my main.tex following line:

```
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
```

then i write a file main.xmpdata and add this lines:

```
\Title{My Title}
\Author{My Name}
\Copyright{Copyright \copyright\ 2018 "My Name"}
\Kewords{KeywordA\sep
         KeywordB\sep
         KeywordC}
\Subject{My Short Discription}
```

after generating the pdf with pdflatex i used a python script based on "pdfminer.six" to extract the metadata

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

fp = open('main.pdf', 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
parser.set_document(doc)

if 'Metadata' in doc.catalog:
    metadata = resolve1(doc.catalog['Metadata']).get_data()
    print(metadata)  # The raw XMP metadata
```

The part with the Keywords then look like this:

```
...<rdf:Bag><rdf:li>KeywordA</rdf:li>\n     <rdf:li>KeywordB...
```

and looking with "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" at the properties of "main.pdf" i find in the properties the following entry in the section keywords:

```
;KeywordA;KeywordB;KeywordC
```

Comment: Is `\Kewords` above intentional or a typo?

Answer (score 3):

[CommonLook](https://commonlook.com/) claim to be "a global leader in electronic document accessibility, providing software products and professional services enabling faster, more cost-efficient, and more reliable processes for achieving compliance with the leading PDF and document accessibility standards, including WCAG, PDF/UA and Section 508."

They provide the [following advice](https://commonlook.com/the-relevance-of-metadata-in-accessible-pdfs/) on PDF metadata:

> Pro Tip: When you’re entering Keywords into the metadata, separate
> them with semicolons as opposed to commas.

although give no further reasoning as to why this is the preferred choice.